# How to call a Google Apps Script from a local Python script

Tags: python, csv, google-apps-script, call, remote-access

I just learned about Google Apps Script and am wondering whether this is a solution for me.

I have a Python script on my desktop which eventually creates a CSV file stored on my computer. In the end it would be great to have the values from this CSV file appended to an existing Google Spreadsheet.

So now I'm wondering: is it possible to create a Google Apps Script which fetches these values from the locally stored CSV, and ideally even to call this Google Apps Script from within my Python script?

Answer (score 0):

Python scripts can invoke Google Apps Scripts via its [Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/). (You'll find a Python Quickstart at that link.)

To go the other way (have Google Apps Script pull the file from your computer) is impossible... but if your Python script puts the csv file into your local Google Drive folder (which syncs to the cloud service), a Google Apps Script can access the sync'd file. You cannot trigger this based on any event - instead, it would need to be time based. (Fine if you know the file is generated periodically, e.g. daily at 3 AM, say.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can go down the execution API route. For a simpler approach, you could have a doGet() function in your script, make a HTTP GET request from Python to the script's URL and pass on the data as an input. Example here: [GAS as backend service](http://marcelkornblum.com/2013/05/16/using-google-apps-scripts-as-a-back-end/)